# How to determine the class of the object extending an abstract class

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to place common functionality for JPA entities in an Abstract class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConcreteClass.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private UUID uuid;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getUuid().hashCode();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof ConcreteClass))
        return false;
    return getUuid().equals(((ConcreteClass) obj).getUuid());
}
```

Is this possible / useful?  How does the Abstract class figure out the concrete class?

Referencing comments below (working code):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj instanceof AbstractEntity && this.getUuid().equals(((AbstractEntity)obj).getUuid()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: well I don't know what to code to identify the concretclass - so no - I  think I need to replace "ConcretClass" with something that maps to the derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. All you really care about here is

```
obj instanceof AbstractEntity && this.getUuid().equals(((AbstractEntity)obj).getUuid())
```

and maybe

```
this.getClass() == obj.getClass()
```

Comment: does instanceof AbstractEntity know the different between two different concrete classes?  Or are you suggesting that this is not necessary?

Comment: I have stated that you don't care about the concrete class. All you care is that the target object is at least an instance of `AbstractEntity` and therefore has a `getUuid()` method. You can *also* check, as shown above, that the classes are equal, if you care for some reason, but you haven't stated one.

Comment: - ok I get it - true as a uuid is unique(?) you are saying that is all that needs to be tested?  The concrete class is not important?

Comment: That is exactly what my entire answer already says, and my comment above as well. I'm not going to restate it yet again.

Comment: just getting a "cannot invoke getUuid() on primitive type Boolean" error on the segment above?

Comment: Parenthesis problem, see edit, but surely you can fix those yourself? Very similar thing in your own code.

Comment: I apologize but I am just trying to learn.  This is what I have:         if (obj instanceof AbstractEntity && this.getUuid().equals((AbstractEntity)obj).getUuid()))
   return true;

Comment: Thanks, no need to apologize, but I would get out of the cut-and-paste mentality ASAP. You can't be a professional programmer that way. You will spend much of your career fixing compilation errors: better start now ;-)

Comment: is this a reasonable approach to placing the equals code in a common class?

Comment: It's reasonable if the UUID is the only thing you ever want to compare, or if the derived classes provide their own implementations which call this one and then maybe proceed to compare other attributes, in the same general way as this.